# Powershell - git path

Tags: git, powershell

I've installed `PowerShell` and `msysgit` but `PowerShell` is not picking up git from the PATH.

The error is:

```
The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spel
```

g of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

The path is being picked up in `cmd.exe` so why not here? Do I need to add an additional environment variable to set the path to git in Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

msysGit is obsolute per the [github repo](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit). The last commit was on May 21st 2016. I have had no problems accessing git through Powershell using [git for windows](https://gitforwindows.org/%20https://gitforwindows.org/) and a entry in my PATH to the `cmd` directory where I installed git for windows.